# ui-sref-active not affecting parent element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Hopefully not a duplicate, but all the other answers I found were related to states.

This works but I also want the parent `<li>` to be affected as well.

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li ng-repeat="title in sidebar.title">
    <div class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-green"><a ui-sref="#"><i ng-class="title.icon"></i>{{title.name}}</a></div>

    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subcat in title.subtitle" ui-sref-active="collapsible-body-active">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-yellow"  ui-sref="{{subcat.state}}">{{subcat.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So if I understand the documentation correctly I should be able to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li ng-repeat="title in sidebar.title" ui-sref-active="collapsible-body-active">
    <div class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-green"><a ui-sref="#"><i ng-class="title.icon"></i>{{title.name}}</a></div>

    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subcat in title.subtitle">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-yellow"  ui-sref="{{subcat.state}}">{{subcat.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Am I misunderstand the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3623Vhm0Dhxf0JUq3whc?p=preview), showing that this scenario should work. BUT - it will work if we have correct `ui-sref` in place

```
// this won't work, because there is missing key setting: ui-sref
// without that, the ui-sref-active cannot work
<li ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a href="#/home" >home</a>
</li>
// this will work as expected
<li ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a ui-sref="parent">parent</a>
</li>
```

And what is the difference with your scenario? I doubt that the state name is "#" as in the snippet above:

```
...<a ui-sref="#">..
```

The state would be like 'subcat.state', and then this should work

```
...<a ui-sref="subcat.state">..
```

You can play with [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3623Vhm0Dhxf0JUq3whc?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the documentation. I was expecting the parent element to be affected, but it seems to be based on the parent state. Thanks.